# Do you know any resources on how to set up a Pyramids Project with multiple Applications?

Tags: python, pyramid

I have read Pyramid documentation and some tutorials, but still don't know how to structure my project the right way.

From what I've learned, you should make everything as a own Application (which I like so I can reuse everything pretty easy), but I can't figure out how to do it "the best way".

Let's say I have a Project called MainApp and I want to use a Blog and a Gallery. Do I make a project for each, build the egg and then just install it to MainApp? Will the setup merge any unnecessary settings into the ini's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyramid uses the [`Configurator.include()` method](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.include) to define boundaries between different pluggable applications, see [Extending An Existing Pyramid Application](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/extending.html).

The `.include()` method accepts either a callable, or a python path to a callable, so you can use both separate eggs and a set of nested packages inside your main project package.

You'll have to decide for yourself if you need some of these pluggable elements to be separate python components (distributed with a setup.py, installable as an egg). If they are intended to be reusable outside the project, then keep them separate.